# Debugger not working in Eclipse while debugging: Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, android-emulator

The debugger is not working in my Eclipse while debugging the project. I have uninstalled JDK, JRE and Eclipse, and have installed all latest versions. JDK7, JRE7 and Eclipse Classic Version: 4.2.1.

But still debugger is not working.. Same Error Comes Up as of my installed previous versions. i.e

> Can't bind to local 8616 for debugger
>
> Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.

I'm using Windows 8 OS. I have tried all other methods. I have set true debuggable from manifest file. I have set the port manually still not worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on testing on both 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 8.

1) Install the 32-bit version of the Android SDK (even on 64-bit windows)

2) Ensure you have a 32-bit Java runtime installed

3) Set the Eclipse exe installed as part of the Android download to run in Windows XP SP3 compatibility mode

4) Configure Eclipse to use ADBHost

Answer (score 0):

There may be a generic problem running on Windows 8.
See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=39286

I have tried many fixes but can not get the emulator and debugger to run consistently.

During investigation I noticed that some of the unzipped Android/Eclipse files are blocked.
I ran streams (a sysinternals tool) to unblock everything in the Android SDK but this did not work for me.

I have also tried switching off my firewall, removing the ":1" entry from the hosts file and ensuring that I am using ADBHOST set to 127.0.0.1. 
These are all suggestions from similar problems but none have them solved my problem.

Comment: thanks for the link Wright. i hv switched my OS to win XP and its working fine now. :P

Comment: thats mean it was due win 8 OS.

Comment: At the moment I have things running by setting eclipse to Windows XP (SP3) compatibility mode. Haven't done enough testing to see how stable this is